# Can't use System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have tried making (my first) a C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This goes well, but if I try using System.Windows.Forms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
            System.MessageBox("hello");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace     'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\Ramy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  5   14  ConsoleApplication1
```

Some details:
- I am using Visual Studio 2012;
- I have installed the .NET Development Kit;
- It is a Console Application.

Maybe it's because on a Console Application can't use System.Windows.Forms?
If so, what program should be? I also have tried with a form, but I was only displaying a window and no code.

Comment: Sometimes error messages actually tell you what's wrong: You are missing an assembly reference. [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Because this is only your first program, it's better to start again and create Windows Forms Application. VS2010 project wizard will take care of many datails regarding the use of windows forms

Comment: The first part of dtb's comment is a little uncalled for. Obviously, the asker is missing an assembly reference. The question was how to fix that problem as the error message doesn't clarify that.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

A console application does not automatically add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Add reference... and then find System.Windows.Forms and add it.

Comment: OK, I am having this problem on an existing project.  I think the project file got hosed, so I created from scratch, overwrote, and added all the existing class, etc. files.  Now, when I go to Add Reference, "System.Windows" and "System.Windows.Forms" are not listed in the ".Net" tab of the browse dialog.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JayImerman its under assemblies tab..  sorry a few years too late.

Comment: The answer was also useful for me (+1) but is it possible to add system.windows.forms once forever in any c# program? Using your answer we need to do this always at any new program.....

Comment: Is it possible to add the reference with "dotnet" cli? For example, "`dotnet add package System.Windows.Forms`" doesn't work: `error: There are no versions available for the package 'System.Windows.Forms'`.

Answer (score 108):

### For Those using Visual Studio 2022 with .Net Core 6.0

Sorry to revive this thread, but I created an account just to do so, as none of the solutions I found searching google for days worked for me alone, and seemed to only bring up only outdated tutorials.

[Not Working =(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ8zy.png)

#### What DID work for me

1. Double click your project (**opening the csproj editor window**)
2. 

**Add the following lines (replacing the existing TargetFramework line):**

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

My window, for referrence, looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

3. **Note Both lines!** I read several solutions / videos that stopped simply after adding the "UseWindowsForms" tag, which did not solve the problem for me, even after unloading and reloading/closing and opening etc.

I stumbled on this solution after applying the "UseWindowsForms" tag, and then in desperation changing my NET framework in properties to 5.0, which caused it to work, and then noted when changing back to 6.0 it still worked.

If you forget the Framework tag in the future, you can reproduce the effect just by flipping your properties back and forth...

4. Right click the project, and go to properties.
5. **[Change the Target framework from .NET 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLTrF.png)...to...[.NET 5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0atP8.png)**
6. Exit back to your code. Which after a few moments will show the [System.Windows.Forms connecting properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJQc.png)
7. Open back up properties.
8. **Change the Target framework from .Net 5.0, back to [.Net 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21woq.png)**

#### Congratulations

**[You have (or at least I have) a .Net 6.0 project that is properly allowing me to use System.Windows.Forms (Including the Clipboard, which I suspect many here are looking for...).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHbry.png)**

I did due diligence on this, testing it multiple times across multiple projects, and it (at least for my setup) consistently works!

BTW. For those wondering. the [STAThread] Attribute tag seen in the pictures is needed to allow the Clipboard class to function. (this is also why I am not using top level statements in the example, but if you don't need that Class, the example works with top level statements (I needed it to show my Clipboard test....)

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent some time with the same problem, using VS 2022 and .NET 6. Adding the '<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>' fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you dude, got this working with vs 2019 for a WPF project with .NET 5

Comment: Entire post can be distilled down to adding the two tags: <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows </TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks!!! This (and @SilentKnight's comment re: <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework><UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>) should be the (new) accepted answer.

Comment: Visual studio generated the program.cs without accessible namespace, internal class Program and static void Main so I can not add [STAThread] to the main method which makes this solution fail on my side. Writing the namespace, class and main method myself causes an exception which states that main is already defined.

Comment: This helped me with a project targeting 4.8, but that had been set, at one point, to targeting 6.0.

Answer (score 23):

Adding System.Windows.Forms reference requires .NET Framework project type:

I was using *.NET Core* project type. This project type doesn't allow us to add assemblies into its project references. I had to move to *.NET Framework* project type before adding `System.Windows.Forms` assembly to my references as described in [Kendall Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646739/3548833) answer.

Note: There is reference `System_Windows_Forms` available under COM tab (for both .NET Core and .NET Framework). It is not the right one. It has to be `System.Windows.Forms` under Assemblies tab.

Answer (score 22):

You have to add the reference of the namespace : System.Windows.Forms to your project, because for some reason it is not already added, so you can add New Reference from Visual Studio menu.

Right click on "Reference" ▶ "Add New Reference" ▶ "System.Windows.Forms"

Comment: Right click on "Reference" ▶ "Add New Reference" ▶ `Assemblies` ▶ "System.Windows.Forms"

Answer (score 15):

If you're using **Visual Studio 2022** open the Project *Properties* and check the *Windows.Forms - Enable Windows Forms for this Project* setting.

[image]

Comment: This saved me. Thank you so much! I wasted so much time searching trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

To add the reference to "System.Windows.Forms", it seems to be a little different for Visual Studio Community 2017.

1)  Go to solution explorer and select references

[image]

2)  Right-click and select Add references
[image]

3)  In Assemblies, check System.Windows.Forms  and press ok

[image]

4) That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Solution Explorer is visible 
In MS Studio 2008 Go to view and click Solution explorer

In Solution explorer go to Reference 
Right click on Reference and select Add Reference..
Select .NET tab
Scroll down till you find System.Drawing -> select it -> click on OK button
Do the same for System.Windows.Forms

When you run your form this will work

(eddie lives somewhere in time)

Answer (score 0):

go to the side project panel, right click on references -> add reference and find System.Windows.Forms

Any time some error like this occurs (some namespace you added is missing that is obviously there) the solution is probably this - adding a reference.

This is needed because your default project does not include everything because you probably wont need it so it saves space. A good practice is to exclude things you're not using.

Answer (score 0):

may be necesssary, 
unreference system.windows.forms 
and reference again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, none of the solutions worked for me (Windows 11, VS 2022). I actually needed to use the "Windows Form app" template. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?view=vs-2022.

Answer (score -2):

just add reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll