# The namespace 'Forms' is not defined for F# creating windows Form in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

The code below produces error "The namespace 'Forms' is not defined"

I have tried the solution of adding System.Windows.Forms framework from Reference Manager,but there's no FrameWork tab in my Reference Manager

[image: Picture]

Other solution is to add the Form library from NUGET/SDK, but there's no option to do that

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let form = new Form()
form.Show()
form.Width <- 400
form.Height <- 400
form.Text <- "Hello from F#!"
```

Comment: Check out [Can't use System.Windows.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646684/cant-use-system-windows-forms) for C#, the same applies to F#.

Comment: I think you have a dotnet core project.  dotnet core pre-3.0 does not support Winforms.