# How to use SystemInformation.PowerStatus in wpf?

Tags: c#, windows

Using visual studio 2019, I tried adding a reference to the WindowsFormsIntegration.dll and then typing the import at the top, not sure what else to do in order to use it.
[Only options I am given with alt enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNI8N.png)
As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646684/cant-use-system-windows-forms) thread, I don't have the option for "Assemblies" in the second answer

Comment: Add `using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;` and also add a reference to the assembly. I suggest `using Forms ...` because otherwise more than one class/enum/etc will have conflicting names (e.g., MessageBox/FlowDirection etc.)

Comment: Note that you can also use the [Win32_Battery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-battery) WMI class instead.

Comment: @Jimi Awesome! Ill give that a go, thank you :)