# Why is SendKeys in C# not working for me?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

So in short, I am trying to write a program, that presses keys.

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("f");
    }
}
```

And i wonder what the hell I am doing wrong.

```
The type or namespace name 'SendKeys' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

This is the Error message I get.
Please help me.

Comment: IIRC Console applications by default do not have a reference to the System.Windows.Forms dll. Right click, add reference, and add it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use System.Windows.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646684/cant-use-system-windows-forms)

Comment: Do you mean right click on the code windows or where?

Comment: Check the documentation about [how to add a reference in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)