# Sendkeys style function for C# console application

Tags: c#, console, sendkeys

I am trying to automate a process using a third party program in a C# console application. After my program starts the third party application (wxPirs.exe) I would like to wait (`Thread.sleep`) for 5 seconds, and then I would like <kbd>alt+f</kbd>, <kbd>down arrow</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> to be entered in the third party program.
I can see this is easily accomplished using sendkeys in a forms application, but my application is console based and I would like for it to stay that way if at all possible. I have created this same program in python and there was a `pynput` function that I could `pip install` that was very easy to use. Is there anything like this in C# that I just haven't came across from my googling and reading documentation?
The code block this would go into is below:

```cs
static void unPirs()
{
    string homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string unpackedPath = homePath + "\\XBLA_Unpacked\\";
    string wxPirsPath = homePath + "\\wxPirs.exe";

    var files = GetAllFiles(unpackedPath);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        var process = Process.Start(wxPirsPath, "\"" + file + "\"");
        Thread.Sleep(7500);
        
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: If it's a console app, read and write to stdout and stdin respectively.

Comment: What exactly does "alt+f, down arrow, enter, enter" do? It sounds like you are opening the"File" menu and selecting some option. Rather than doing whatever it is through the "File" menu, it can probably be done programmatically instead. So what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, it opens the file menu, selects extract all, and then selects the default extraction folder. Since this is a third party program that I have no control over I didn't think there would be any way to do that programmatically, but I am a total newbie so I could definitely be wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is SendKeys in C# not working for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67414414/11683)

Comment: See if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939988/3057246

Comment: 1. If the `exe` is a `.net` exe you can refer it to your project and may call the file open function from there. 2. See if that `exe` support input parameters so that you can pass it when doing `Process.Start("exe",args)` 3. There is `SendKeys.Send()` using that you can send keystrokes 4. You can use `kebd_event` form API also to send keystrokes pls see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939988/3057246 for reference.