# How to print using the windows Print Pictures function

Tags: windows, image, printing

Windows has a really useful right click -> print function for most files, but I can't figure out how to arbitrarily call this function. I've found out how to do a *direct* print by calling

```
rundll32 shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "Absolute\Path\To\File" "Printer Name"
```

and I can open the photo *viewer* by calling

```
rundll32 shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen Absolute\Path\To\File
```

However, the intermediate print setup GUI I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it! Here's an example C# program:

Few things to note:

- The program owns the dialog, so it needs a while loop to stay alive
- If you're going to use this, you might need [this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646684/cant-use-system-windows-forms#9646739)

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PrintGUI // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing file:");
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            OpenPrintPictures(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00000122-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IDropTarget
        {
            int DragEnter(
                [In] System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDataObj,
                [In] int grfKeyState,
                [In] Point pt,
                [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);

            int DragOver(
                [In] int grfKeyState,
                [In] Point pt,
                [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);

            int DragLeave();

            int Drop(
                [In] System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDataObj,
                [In] int grfKeyState,
                [In] Point pt,
                [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Open Print Pictures dialog
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">File to print</param>
        public static void OpenPrintPictures(string filename)
        {
            var dataObj = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, new string[] { filename });
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(4);
            var buffer = new byte[] { 5, 0, 0, 0 };

            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            dataObj.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", memoryStream);

            var CLSID_PrintPhotosDropTarget = new Guid("60fd46de-f830-4894-a628-6fa81bc0190d");
            var dropTargetType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_PrintPhotosDropTarget, true);
            var dropTarget = (IDropTarget)Activator.CreateInstance(dropTargetType);

            dropTarget.Drop(dataObj, 0, new Point(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```