# How can i upload a file to my webserver in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Hello i need help i have got this code:

My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\temp.jpg", "localhost/upload.php")

And i want to pick a file using a text box instead of uploading C:\temp.jpg
So can anyone help me?

Comment: Take in mind that Stack Overflow is **not** a help forum / bulletin board.  Therefore "Please help me" decoration and nagging is entirely inappropriate. Questions should contain a bit more explanation than that, prior attempts and research - to remain useful to others. And refrain from introducing follow-up questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here, there is an example of OpenFileDialog use:

[How to add a Browse To File dialog to a VB.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283423/how-to-add-a-browse-to-file-dialog-to-a-vb-net-application)

You'll have to put this, inside a button click event.

For your example, you just have do adapt the code, that will be, something like this:

```
Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim strFileName As String

        fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        fd.FilterIndex = 2
        fd.RestoreDirectory = True

        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            ' Your code
            My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(fd.FileName, "localhost/upload.php")

        End If
```

Comment: This works thank you i also need to know how to open the browser after the image is uploaded so i can view the image instantly do you know how thanks!

Comment: Well, to open a url on default browser, you can use: Process.Start("http://www.exampleurl.com") after the code that makes the file upload.

Comment: i know but how can i do Process.Start("exampleurl.com/image name.png")