# Allow user to choose file and trigger SSIS/ ETL pacakge

Tags: ssis, etl, talend

Is there a way a user can manually choose the file and then somehow trigger the SSIS package or ETL package. I need the users to be manually able to select the file (file format will be the same), the file name will be different and when they for example press okay, start processing it will use either SSIS or Talend to perform the necessary steps that will then provide them with an output on their desktop or in a certain location. Please let me know if this is possible and how this can be achieved. I am assuming this would have to be done via .NET app that can then use SSIS package. If that is the case, any tips of where I would start would be extremely helpful.

Comment: How complex is the ETL? Because of all the user interaction required it's usually better to just do the whole thing in whatever app you are using to select the file. For example a user also like to know the progress of the ETL and the outcome (success, fail) and possible an error log. What version of SSIS, and why are you mixing up talend in this?

Comment: Talend or SSIS wither or would work. The ETL isn't too complex but it will require either of these tools. Basically its reformatting the input file and creating an output file. Log file is not necessary would be goo though. I don't necessary need a progress bar, more of just a pop up notification/ confirmation stating the Process has completed. But the idea is that the end user should have ability to select the file. They will be exporting a file from another system and the because the export is manual the file name would be manual, hence giving users the ability to select the file.

Comment: I can't speak for Talend but SSIS for example would normally run on the server (i.e. you wouldn't pay licence to install on a client), so that server needs access to the file you have specified (unless you include logic to upload the file to the server so it can access it). Anyway, if you are version 2012 of SSIS or higher, this is a pretty good guide to what you want: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biblog/2013/05/07/step-by-step-of-executing-ssis-2012-package-through-stored-procedure/

Comment: ... you just use normal data access to execute those stored procedures. But be aware that the path you pass in for the source file needs to be relative to the SSIS Server. i.e. C drive on your local machine needs to be converted to a UNC (for example `\\mypc\c$\Folder\MyFile.TXT`), and the SSIS service account needs access to it.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. I would like to give the end user the ability to select the File to perform SSIS ETL on.

Comment: For that you need a user interface. Here is an example in VB.Net. Again I googled it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283423/how-to-add-a-browse-to-file-dialog-to-a-vb-net-application. I am not answering anything here, just commenting. If the last link was of no use to you I think you may be missing something. Have you built the package yet?

Comment: Maybe you mean you want to run the package interactively and prompt? Bad idea but.... to do that the user needs to install SSDT, and you need yo have a script task in your package that prompts for a path.

Comment: Yeah...that is exactly what I am stating. This is an interim step to a temporary process.

Comment: First use this to get the package prompting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107289/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-from-an-ssis-package (this was top of my google search)

Comment: You would need to create a script in vb or c# that prompts a messagebox and browse. First thing to do is independently create code that does that then run in script object.